# google adwords with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-ads-api

I am tracking user session with the help of google adwords conversion.
I am writing the code code in Javascript and passing the values in php.
My whole code is correct but when I look at the page source (ctrl + u), the google coversion label is not showing.
I dont know what is happening, can anybody help me to sort out this problem?

I'm stuck in between the project, I also attached the screenshot of the page source

[image]

```
     <!-- Google Code for Search-UAE-English-Skincare-mobiiwold Conversion Page -->

      <script type="text/javascript">
      var conversion_label;
          $(document).ready(function() {
              var link = $(location).attr("href");
              if(link.includes("campaign/skin-care/")) {
                  conversion_label = "VEa_CMe_rmUQ45-p2gM";
              } else if( link.includes("campaign/obesity/")) {
                   conversion_label = "-Xq-CJCtwGUQ45-p2gM";
              } else if(link.includes("campaign/al-wasl-branch/")) {
                   conversion_label =" KhRoCMX8tGUQ45-p2gM";
              } else if(link.includes("campaign/worried-about-hairloss/")) {
                  conversion_label = "T8nbCJSR7mUQ45-p2gM";
              } else if(link.includes("campaign/ar-hair-loss/")) {
                  conversion_label = "7MhmCMSqgWYQ45-p2gM";
              } else if(link.includes("campaign/ar-skin-care/")) {
                  conversion_label  = "ef7rCLapwGUQ45-p2gM";
              } else if(link.includes("campaign/ar-obesity/")) {
                  conversion_label  = "YPVwCJyJuWUQ45-p2gM";
              } else if(link.includes("campaign/ar-allergy/")) {
                  conversion_label  == "95cLCNuzv2UQ45-p2gM";
              } else if(link.includes("campaign/ar-al-wasl-branch/")) {
                  conversion_label  = "OKx6CJ2nyGUQ45-p2gM";
              } 
          });         

          /* <![CDATA[ */
          var google_conversion_id = 994725859;
          var google_conversion_language = "en";
          var google_conversion_format = "3";
          var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
          var google_conversion_label =<?php echo $conversion_label; ?>;
          var google_remarketing_only = false;


          /* ]]> */
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
      </script>
      <noscript>
          <div style="display:inline;">
              <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/994725859/?label=<?php echo $conversion_label; ?>;guid=ON&amp;script=0" />
          </div>
      </noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the JS variable `conversion_label` to the correct value but later read out the PHP variable `$conversion_label`. I don't see why PHP is needed here, just change your line to

```
var google_conversion_label = conversion_label;
```